# How do you block a URL path with Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, web

I'm currently testing out Azure Application Gateway (Standard v2).

What I'm trying to do is block / blackhole / reject traffic that hits example.com/manager/, or example.com/admin/*, etc.

I'm sure this probably could be done with an additional web server and path-based rules pointing to it, but that seems a bit excessive for what I'm hoping would be native functionality or options to take care of this.

I found a post on TechNet that asked a very similar question, but unfortunately has no answer. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5093237-36ce-4082-99c9-f14dd3faf715/block-a-url-path-with-azure-application-gateway?forum=websitesvirtualmachinesonwinserver&prof=required

Thank you!